# Creating file with exception message

Tags: java, appium

I'm working on emulator and when something fails I'm taking screenshot and also want to take exception message, then put it into one directory named by date.

So the question is how to do it, because so far I've made try catch where exception goes

```
try{
    setup.waitForElementByName("rates");
    setup.goTo("right");
    setup.tapByName("Favouritess"); //this cause exception
    setup.waitForElementById("list_content");
}catch (WebDriverException e){
    setup.takeScreenshotAndLogs(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
}
```

As you see i cause exception and call method:

```
public void takeScreenshotAndLogs(String exceptionName, String exceptionMessage) throws IOException {
    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    int year = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR);
    int mouth = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH);
    int day = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int hour = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.MINUTE);
    int second = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.SECOND);
    String directory = "fails/screenshots/"
            +year +"-"
            +mouth +"-"
            +day +" "
            +hour +"."
            +minute +"."
            +second +"/";

    File scrFile = driver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    File targetFileScreenshot = new File (directory +exceptionName +".png");
    FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, targetFileScreenshot);
}
```

I use there Calendar to create directory name then take screenshot, and save it on directory.

Now only creating txt file with exception message left and I hope you will help me how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use one of the many available logging frameworks (logback, log4j, …) to log your errors?

Comment: @raphaëλ I'll check log4j :) thx